# How can I manually accept users that signup using Azure B2C active directory?

Tags: asp.net, access-control, policies, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure B2C to allow users to signup and login to my asp.net web form. By default, users are granted access as soon as the finish the signup policy form. How can I make it so that I have to manually grant them access? I noticed in the policies configuration that there is a slider button to block access to users but I want this slider button to be blocked by default. Or if there is another way around this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be a [custom attribute/claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr).  You could set that claim to `true` via the [Graph Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) when you wanted to enable a user.  In your app, you check that claim and display the appropriate message to the user if they are not enabled yet.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I've never used the graph Api before. Do you think you can provide me with the code that would set for this?

Comment: sure thing.  see the link in the answer 'graph api'.  it's a great walkthrough that has source in github :).  specifically [this part of the guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#use-custom-attributes)

Comment: I read that only strings are available for custom attributes. Will I need each user to write something in the custom attribute in order to make this work? I'm a little confused as to how I should incorporate this. Any ideas?

Comment: the attribute is at the user level so each user will have a flag indicating whether their account has been granted access.  hope that helps :)

Comment: oh ok so this custom attribute won't be a field that they have to fill out upon signing up?

Comment: Ok so I added Graph Api to my root folder and changed the app settings with the proper keys and tenant name. All this was done user azure app service editor. Now I'm stuck on how to rebuild the sample. Is it possible to rebuild the sample inside app service editor? Or did I need to do change app settings and rebuild before uploading the files to my directory?

Comment: also can you please specify whether the custom attribute needs to be a boolean or string? Or it doesnt matter?

Comment: that is correct, the user won't fill it out.  you will control it behind the scenes.  correct, change app settings, rebuild then perform the upload.  I would use boolean since there are only 2 states: enabled and disabled.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me. Is there any way of rebuilding without visual studio. If not, it's okay I'll ask someone who has it to rebuild for me.

Comment: you're welcome.  you need VS (if it was [dotnet core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd) then the story would be different but it's a .net 4.5 prj).

Comment: Ok so I rebuilt it. Which file(s) do I need to upload to my root folder for my site? The guide you linked mentioned that I will open Graph Api using cmd, does this mean I don't need to upload any Graph Api files into my site's root folder? Which files am I uploading exactly? Only the app.config file correct?

Comment: nothing goes into your site.  the sample prj shows you how to call the graph api.  you will need to call these same urls from within your site.

Comment: ok and I set the Boolean to true by default? And then when I want to grant access to the user I set the Boolean to false manually?

Comment: true by default is fine.  then when you grant access you call the graph api and set the value to false.  Doesn't have to be manual.

Comment: in my case I would want to manually grant them access so that's fine. Thank you for clearing everything up for me. Now I'm just completely clueless as to how I program all of this. To set default value as true and to disable access to the user, is this all programmed using graph API?